# Apache2 Does Not Start

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

I recently was having troube getting Apache2 to work with php7.1.
I enabled the php module by using `sudo a2enmod php7.1` and that worked.

I updated my server using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After I had updated my server I restarted it.

my wordpress site was no longer working and it was just displaying the .php page as plain text again.

I assumed it was was the same issue I was having before so I manually tried to re-enable the php7.1 module again using the same command mentioned above (`sudo a2enmod php7.1`). After running that command I attempted to restart Apache2 with:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Only to provide me with this error:

```
    Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So of course I run `systemctl status apache2.service` to try to see what the issue was.

This is was I was provided with:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-06-25 23:54:16 CDT; 7min ago
  Process: 1163 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 25 23:54:16 UndergroundSpecInc systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 25 23:54:16 UndergroundSpecInc apachectl[1163]: apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax e
Jun 25 23:54:16 UndergroundSpecInc apachectl[1163]: Action 'start' failed.
Jun 25 23:54:16 UndergroundSpecInc apachectl[1163]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 25 23:54:16 UndergroundSpecInc systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 25 23:54:16 UndergroundSpecInc systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 25 23:54:16 UndergroundSpecInc systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

So to follow the trail I investigate line 146 of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to find this:

```
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
```

At this point I am stuck because I don't see anything wrong with that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I have answered my own question!

To fix this I had to first start by completely removing everything installed that was related to php. (This is because I have updated php a few times on this installation of Ubuntu so there were conflicts from previous versions.)

```
sudo apt-get purge php*
```

Next I found this write up that explained that on the newest version of Ubuntu (18.04) will automatically install php7.2 by just using "php" in the apt-get command. So to reinstall I simply used:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then once that was finished adjusting packages from purging php* I reinstalled php with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php
```

Once that finished up I doubble checked my installation version by running:

```
php -v
```

This gave me an output that said I was running php 7.2. Great!

I still needed to reinstall the modules for php7.2 since they got removed after the purge. That was done with:

```
apt-get install php-pear php-fpm php-dev php-zip php-curl php-xmlrpc php-gd php-mysql php-mbstring php-xml libapache2-mod-php
```

After this finished up I re-enabled the php module for Apache2 by running:

```
sudo an2enmod php7.2
```

That was successful! So the last step in makeing sure everything was running right I restarted Apache 2 with:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

It was a successful restart! I headed over to my browser and navigated to the php site running on that server and it loaded perfectly!

I would like to credit [this site](https://thishosting.rocks/install-php-on-ubuntu/) for helping out a ton!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution! But [it would be great](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) if you could include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. That way someone else can find the information even if that linked page disappears.

Comment: @JennyD In a few mins I will add a detailed answer